# How can I split a dictionary into groups based on similar keys then create an array of those groups with updated keys?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, grouping

I have a dictionary with keys that are appended with _0, _1, _2.

```
let dict = ["a_0":"0", "b_1":"1", "c_0":"2", "d_2":"3"]
```

I want to take every key with similar underscore and whichever number and put them into a group separate from the other keys. Any key with _0 should be in one group, _1 another group, _2 another group...

```
let arrOfGroupedDictsWithSimilarKeys = [["a_0":"0", "c_0":"2"], ["b_1":"1", ], ["d_2":"3"] ]
```

And then I want to update the keys in each group by removing the underscore and number from all the keys but still keep everything in their groups.

The outcome should be

```
let arrOfGroupedDictsWithKeysChanged = [["a":"0", "c":"2"], ["b":"1"], ["d":"3"] ]
```

Comment: Not my downvote but your question shows no effort at all to solve your own problem. Do you really wonder why your question got downvoted?

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for the response. I actually tried to solve this problem for 10 hrs straight and I had a number of things that I tried. If I posted the code it would’ve been a very long question and I notice long questions tend not to get answered. So it was either get straight to the point or just post a bunch of code that didn’t work. You gave a valid reason for downvoting but the person who downvoted may have downvoted for a different, maybe they felt it was just a silly question? Whatever the reason they should’ve left a response.

Comment: Talk about what you tried from a high level, and how the results failed to meet your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func transformDict(dict: [String: String]) -> [[String: String]] {
    var temp: [String: [String: String]] = [:]
    for (key, value) in dict {
        let components = key.components(separatedBy: "_")
        if components.count == 2 {
            let groupKey = components[1]
            let dictKey = components[0]
            if temp[groupKey] != nil {
                temp[groupKey]?[dictKey] = value
            } else {
                temp[groupKey] = [dictKey: value]
            }
        }
    }

    let res = Array(temp.values)
    return res
}

let res = transformDict(dict: ["a_0":"0",
                               "b_1":"1",
                               "c_0":"2",
                               "d_2":"3"])
print(res)
```

Comment: You can get ride of that nil comparison using Swift 4 dictionary default value `temp[groupKey, default: [dictKey: value]][dictKey] = value`. Expanding a bit `if let groupKey = components.last, let dictKey = components.first, components.count == 2 {
            temp[groupKey, default: [dictKey: value]][dictKey] = value
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Just another similar way:

```
let dict = ["a_0":"0", "b_1":"1", "c_0":"2", "d_2":"3"]

 let result = Dictionary(grouping: dict)
              {(key, value) ->  String in return key.components(separatedBy: "_").last!}.values
              .map{Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:$0.map{($0.key.components(separatedBy: "_").first!, $0.value)})}

print (result)

  // [["c": "2", "a": "0"], ["d": "3"], ["b": "1"]]
```

Comment: that is one looooong line.